# Is it possible to get cv2 frame from another process?

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I am trying to run simple motion detection with opencv. Got that working. Now that process is running as a background process.

I want to be able to see the processed image by connecting to it via flask.

How do you start a process and connect to it at any point in time to see the output of that processed frame w/o writing the image to a database? Is there a way?

would appreciate any tutorial /reference / code

Comment: You can of course transfer your frame to another process, but what you want to do seems more like streaming rather than that. In that case, this may help you. http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

1. You can write to an intermediary file. 2nd process can read this file, only issue is that you get a "flickering" effect because the 2nd process might be trying to read the image b4 the 1st process has a chance to read it in entirety
2. You can try and replicate the same with [pyperclip](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip), but not sure how you'd do multiple clipboards

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, after figuring it out!
Having no code with a question is a good reason for some down-vote trolls. Once you have the first down-vote, it works as an invitation for those who want to get a badge by using their first down-vote.

Comment: Thanks @Totoro. I figured there was some incentive for doing so. I didn't post any code b/c it was too simplistic so i figured most opencv (which I tagged) people would know what im talking about. I'll post code next time